# msqli select from table where a =1 or a =2

Tags: mysqli, where-in, mysqli-multi-query

Looking for the correct use for the Where and In clause. If this is not correct could you let me know the right way to use it please

```
    mysqli_query=($connection,"select * from tablename where a=1 or a=2 and c=1 and d=2);
```

I am trying to do the query this way using the in clause

```
    mysqli_query=($connection,"select * from tablename where a in(1,2) and c=1 and d=2);
```

is thsi the correct way to use the where and In when you are looking for more than one value in a?

Many thanks
P

Comment: Yes, the second is correct. Did you try it out? The first would need a `()` group like `where (a=1 or a=2) and c=1 and d=2` to give the equivalent result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't put values in the query directly, you'll have [SQL Injection vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) if those values comes from a user input and/or be more error prone.

Second, yours IN clause is correct, have a look at the MySql manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).
Using Mysqli you should prepare your statements so they get correctly escaped, this way:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE a IN(?,?) and c=? and d=?")
$stmt->bind_param("iiii", 1, 2, 1, 2);
$stmt->execute();
```

have a look at the whole mysqli manual about the prepare statement [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).